# Using windows DDK with C#

Tags: c#, windows, wdk

For a little background story, I work in a computer lab and we need to have an easy method to disable certain network protocol bindings on adapters based on their PCI bus locations.

So far I have written a C# command line utility to find them, get their bus locations, netcfginstanceid, etc. The one thing I haven't figured out how to do is remove bindings on those adapters, I could go through and remove them in the registry but it would still show up in adapter settings.

Eventually I found out some neat utilities in the windows DDK, especially the bindview sample program, what I want to do is take the NetCfgAPI included in the bindview sample and use it in my C# program, the problem is they are C++ files. I have tried using MIDL to convert them into a .ddl or .tlb that I can then use pinvoke on but I know little about pinvoke and the MIDL compiler comes up with errors such as "midl : command line error MIDL1003 : error returned by the C preprocessor (4)".

My question is, is there an easier way to do this? and if there is not, what is the best way to go about converting the NetCfgApi c++ files into something usable in C#?

I could write the utility in C++ but I am more comfortable using C#.

Answer (score 2):

You could try compiling this stuff with C++/CLI as a DLL. In the project settings under compiler, mention that you do not want CLR, it will ease the compilation.

Then you should be able to add that DLL as a reference in your C# project.

Comment: is there an easy way to do this using visual studio 2010?

Comment: Well... "easy" is always relative to other things. Create a project, select that you want a C++/CLI project then add all your sources to that project. Also, you want to make sure that the compilation switches are the same in VS than with the DDK compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Use ATL or something with C++ (not managed, straight C++) to create a COM object wrapper for the C++ code.  Then use COM-interop from C# to talk to your COM object.

Comment: I'm looking into that right now thanks, I don't know much about this stuff as I'm just getting into it so I'm doing the msdn tutorial first